# How can i covert plain text to unique url

Tags: php

I am learning php with a target site in mind, the target site is a site where people can post their items for sale. i have successfully created a form for inserting data from users to my database, and also have pulled the data from the database for users  to view. Now my problem is how to make the title of each item posted by any user to have a unique url. Also i want it in such a way that each title when clicked will take the viewer to see more details of the particular item.

Here is the code that echos the data to my webpage:

```
<?php foreach ($itemarray as $itemarrays): ?>
 <div style="width:200px; float: left; height: 100px;">
<div style="background:#999; border-radius: 10px; text-align:center; float: left; width:100px; float:left; ">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($itemarrays['date'], ENT_QUOTES,
'UTF-8'); ?></div>
<div style="background:#063; width: 100px; float:left; height: 100px;">Image</div>
</div>


<div style="background:#F6F; float: left; width: 500px; height: 100px;">
<?php
echo $itemarrays['title']; ?>

<div style="background: #9FF; float: left; width: 100%;">
<?php
echo $itemarrays['description']; ?>
</div>

</div>


<div style="background: #9F3; float: right; width: 125px; height: 100px;">
<?php
echo $itemarrays['location']; ?></div>


<?php endforeach; ?>

  </div>
    </div>.
```

please any help on how to pass through this jinx?

Answer (score 0):

You mean a unique url based on the entered title?

If so, I would do the following:

- Select the number of items in the database where title = entered title. (SELECT COUNT if you use mysql)
- - If that returns 0: The part of the url representing the item can be the same as the title.
- - Otherwise, you coult append the count-result - or the count-result + 2 for more "intuitive" urls, so if 3 items are named "foo", the url of the first would be e.g. '.../item-details/foo', of the second '.../item-details/foo2', of the third '.../item-details/foo3' etc.